# Exclude entity bean attributes from hibernate query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm new to this hibernate/jpa stuff so bear with me..

I've generated an entity bean and it works fine, but I would like to add some extra attributes to it and this causes hibernate to complain that the extra attributes aren't in the table's field list..

Is there a keyword to exclude these attributes from hibernate's query??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mark them as `@Transient`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you for the fast response!